# Google Guice and Servlets

Tags: java, guice

Does anyone have anything that is remotely helpful regarding implementation of Google Guice with a simple MVC Model 2 web app? I'm just using POJO's, Servlets, and JSP's and I'm having a hardtime finding anything on the subject. I've looked at Google's Guice homepage, but it's not very friendly for beginners. If you have any google reference material that would be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The wiki has a whole section about this subject: http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/ServletModule

Comment: Thanks for the help. After I typed this question I went back to the wiki and many things started making sense for some reason :/